# Create log file of all systems that connect to SOCKS server

Tags: socks-proxy, privoxy

I want to keep track of all the systems that attempt to connect to the SOCKS server (With authentication). The server is SUSE 11 SP3

Comment: What SOCKS server software are you using?

Comment: @mtak socks5 is what I'm using